# JavaScript equation calculating incorrect values

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having difficulty with the sum of digits depreciation equation. The sum of digits equation if the last part of the function in the bottom else statement. There is an error some where in the algorithm and I have not been able to find it.

The table it prints should look like this:

[image: correct results]

But it is printing like this:

[image: incorrect results]

```
    function calDepreciation() {

    var rowNum = document.getElementById('myTable').rows.length;

    if(rowNum > 1){
        for(i = 0; i < (rowNum-1); i++){
            document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);
        }
    }
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var maxRow = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName(
            "tr").length;
    var assetVal = document.getElementById("assetVal").value;
    var assetLife = document.getElementById("assetLife").value;
    var salVal = document.getElementById("salvageVal").value;
    var eq = "";
    var year = 1;

    var radios = document.getElementsByName('choice');
    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            eq = radios[i].value;

            break;
        }
    }

    if (eq == "straightLine") {
        var depreciation = (assetVal - salVal) / assetLife;
        var aDepreciation = depreciation;
        assetVal = assetVal - salVal;

        for (i = 0; i < assetLife; i++) {
            assetVal = assetVal - depreciation;
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var num = 2;
            cell1.innerHTML = year;
            cell2.innerHTML = parseFloat(Math.round(assetVal * 100) / 100)
                    .toFixed(2);
            cell3.innerHTML = parseFloat(
                    Math.round(depreciation * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            cell4.innerHTML = parseFloat(
                    Math.round(aDepreciation * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

            aDepreciation = aDepreciation + depreciation;
            year = year + 1;
        }
    } else if (eq == "doubleDeclining") {
        var depreciation = (1 / assetLife) * assetVal;
        var aDepreciation = depreciation;
        assetVal = assetVal - depreciation;

        for (i = 0; i < assetLife; i++) {

            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var num = 2;
            cell1.innerHTML = year;
            cell2.innerHTML = parseFloat(Math.round(assetVal * 100) / 100)
                    .toFixed(2);
            cell3.innerHTML = parseFloat(
                    Math.round(depreciation * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            cell4.innerHTML = parseFloat(
                    Math.round(aDepreciation * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);


            year = year + 1;
            depreciation = (1 / assetLife) * assetVal;
            assetVal = assetVal - depreciation;
            aDepreciation = aDepreciation + depreciation;
        }
    } else {
        assetVal = assetVal - salVal;
        var s = 0;
        var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("assetLife").value, 10);
        for(i = 1; i <= (assetLife); i++){
            s = s + i;
        }

        var p = (((n + 1) - year))/ s * 1.0;

        var depreciation = assetVal * p;
        var aDepreciation = depreciation;
        assetVal = assetVal - depreciation;

        for (i = 0; i < assetLife; i++) {

            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var num = 2;
            cell1.innerHTML = year;
            cell2.innerHTML = parseFloat(Math.round(assetVal * 100) / 100)
                    .toFixed(2);
            cell3.innerHTML = parseFloat(
                    Math.round(depreciation * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            cell4.innerHTML = parseFloat(
                    Math.round(aDepreciation * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);


            year = year + 1;
            p = (n + 1 - year) / s * 1.0;
            depreciation = p * assetVal * 1.0;
            assetVal = assetVal - depreciation;
            aDepreciation = aDepreciation + depreciation;
        }
    }
}
```

If anything could help me find where its going wrong  i would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: How about posting just the code without DOM manipulation?

Comment: Its better if you could provide the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Its this portion here

```
    assetVal = assetVal - salVal;
    var s = 0;
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("assetLife").value, 10);
    for(i = 1; i <= (assetLife); i++){
        s = s + i;
    }

    var p = (((n + 1) - year))/ s * 1.0;

    var depreciation = assetVal * p;
    var aDepreciation = depreciation;
    assetVal = assetVal - depreciation;

    for (i = 0; i < assetLife; i++) {

        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var num = 2;
        cell1.innerHTML = year;
        cell2.innerHTML = parseFloat(Math.round(assetVal * 100) / 100)
                .toFixed(2);
        cell3.innerHTML = parseFloat(
                Math.round(depreciation * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        cell4.innerHTML = parseFloat(
                Math.round(aDepreciation * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);


        year = year + 1;
        p = (n + 1 - year) / s * 1.0;
        depreciation = p * assetVal * 1.0;
        assetVal = assetVal - depreciation;
        aDepreciation = aDepreciation + depreciation;
    }
```